# Unable to save edits

Tags: android

I've created an app in Android Studio. When I run the application and make edits to a view and click save the changes seem to save but when I got back in the settings return to the default.

I've updated my spinner that is pulling the data and making the association. The expected behavior is when I make changes to the view they save rather than go back to the default

```
Spinner spinner = findViewById(R.id.CourseSpinner);
        ArrayAdapter<Course> courseArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, repository.getCourses());
        spinner.setAdapter(courseArrayAdapter);
        for (int i=0; i<repository.getCourses().size();i++) {
            Course course = repository.getCourses().get(i);
            if(course.getCourseID() == courseID) {
                int pos = courseArrayAdapter.getPosition(course);
                spinner.setSelection(pos);
            }
            if (repository.getCourses().get(i).getCourseID() == courseID) spinner.setSelection(i);

            List<Course> Courses = repository.getCourses();
            List<String> CourseName = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Course course1 : Courses) {
                CourseName.add(course.getCourseName());
            }
        }



        spinner.setAdapter(courseArrayAdapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                List<Course> allCourses = repository.getCourses();
                editCourseID.setText(String.valueOf(allCourses.get(i).getCourseID()));
            }
```

Comment: "When I run the application and make edits to a view and click save the changes seem to save" - what makes you think the changes _seem_ to save?

Comment: And nowhere you told where you try to save them to. You should have started with it. Already in the subject.